# Gerar Html segundo objeto Json

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso receber um Json com a seleção das atividades e gerar o HTML segundo esses dados.

Acredito que deve ficar mais ou menos desse jeito, alguém consegue me dar alguma dica para melhorar?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var CodigoMilestone = $("#CodigoMilestone");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Dashboard/GetAtividades",
        sucess: function (atividades) {

            if (atividades != null) {
                $(atividades).each(function (i) {

                    var div = "<div> <table>";
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    div +=
                    tr += "<td>" + atividades[i].InicioCedo;
                    tr += "<td>" + atividades[i].TempoRevisado;
                    tr += "<td>" + atividades[i].TerminoCedo;                        
                    div.append(tr);

                    tr += "<td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + atividades.Descricao;
                    tr += "<td>";
                    div.append(tr);

                    tr += "<td>" + atividades[i].InicioTarde;
                    tr += "<td>" + atividades[i].Folga;
                    tr += "<td>" + atividades[i].TerminoTarde;
                    div.append(tr);

                })
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Abaixo um objeto Json:

```
[{"Codigo":7,"Descricao":"Atividade 1","CodigoMilestone":6,"TempoRevisado":2,"Inicio":"\/Date(1445738400000)\/","InicioCedo":"\/Date(1445738400000)\/","InicioTarde":"\/Date(-62135589600000)\/","TerminoCedo":"\/Date(1445911200000)\/","TerminoTarde":"\/Date(-62135589600000)\/","Ativo":true,"Milestone":null,"Dependencia":[],"Dependencia1":[]},{"Codigo":8,"Descricao":"Ativade 2","CodigoMilestone":6,"TempoRevisado":2,"Inicio":"\/Date(1445997600000)\/","InicioCedo":"\/Date(1445997600000)\/","InicioTarde":"\/Date(1445911200000)\/","TerminoCedo":"\/Date(1446084000000)\/","TerminoTarde":"\/Date(1446084000000)\/","Ativo":true,"Milestone":null,"Dependencia":[],"Dependencia1":[]}]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o Objeto de atividades para ver como ele fica, esta tendo algum problema ou e so questão de otimização de código/produzir um código mais elegante ?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta. Ainda não está funcionando.

Comment: se você fizer um `console.log(atividades);` você recebe algum retorno do php ?

Comment: Meu projeto é em ASP.net MVC

Comment: Entendi,  o erro esta na sua div, vou fazer um exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código possui alguns erros como a syntax do $.each e o uso de um seletor do jquery,vamos ao seguinde exemplo,

Digamos que você possua uma div com id conteudo assim:

```
  <div id="conteudo"></div>
```

Então eu quero poder colocar as minhas informações que estão em um objeto chamado atividades dentro dessa div.

```
 if (atividades != null) {
    var table = '';
    $.each(atividades,function (key,val) {
        table += '<table>';
        table += '<thead><tr><th>Código</th><th>Descrição</th></tr></thead>';
        table += '<tbody><tr><td>'+val.Codigo+'</td><td>'+ val.Descricao+'</td></tr></tbody>';
        table += '</table>'
    })
    $("#conteudo").append(table);
}
```

A validação  ok,  depois percorro o objeto colocando os meus valores em uma table, e depois do each eu dou um append.

Veja funcionando no [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/3a7p7yxo/3/)

Agora é so você trabalhar no seu html e colocar o restante dos teus valores na table.

Comment: Eu tenho que fazer uma tabela para cada atividade, assim como mostrado na pergunta (atualizei a pergunta)

Comment: apenas passe a table por string dentro do each, resposta atualizada, exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/3a7p7yxo/3/